# custom tableview cell doesn't appear

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
import UIKit

class anasayfaVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView1: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView1.delegate = self
        tableView1.dataSource = self
}
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! FeedCell
        cell.deneme.image = UIImage(named: "naruto")
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: I add the custom view cell but at the screen just appear tableview cell with nothing

Comment: `tableView1.reloadData()`? Whats the frame of `tableView1`?

Comment: Your custom cell has only this image? Could you try put a text to see if it appear?

Comment: yeah I tried every way

Comment: tableview1 is my tableview

Answer (score 0):

did you register your tableview as

```
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "FeedCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell") ?
```